# How to create drop down multi select with live search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have to make a functionality similar to this https://www.healthians.com/ in search in which we can select drom drop down also as well we can type and live search is done . I have used https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Multiple-Select-UI-jQuery.html this jquery plugin and was able to get list effect but the result is shown in div if i do input type text in result area then makes problem with live search .

Is there any jquery plugin which can help me in this.

```
<div class="custom-result-section test" placeholder="Find Your Test" > </div>
<button class="tg-btn" type="submit"><i class="lnr lnr-magnifier"></i></button>

                                         </fieldset>
                                          <div class="div_search_box drop-down" style="display: none;">
                                             <span class="cross remove-icon "><img src="images/remove-icon.png" height="50px" width="50px"></span>

                                             <div class="jquery-multiple-select style="float:left;margin-right:50px;"  >
                                                <ul>
                                                  <?php foreach($featured_test as $faetur){  ?>
                                                       <li  data-test-id="<?php echo $faetur['id']; ?>" ><?php echo $faetur['name']; ?></li>

                                                  <?php } ?>


                                                </ul>
                                             </div>

                                             <div class="jquery-multiple-select " style="float:right;margin-right:30px;">
                                                <ul>

                                                  <?php foreach($labbogy_health_pkg as $faetur){  ?>
                                                       <li data-pkg-id="<?php echo $faetur['id']; ?>"><?php echo $faetur['name']; ?></li>
                                                  <?php } ?>

                                                </ul>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
```

script

```
 $(".custom-result-section").on('click', function(){
         $('.div_search_box').css('display','block');   
    });
     $(".cross").on('click', function(){

        $('.div_search_box').css('display','none');

     });
```

// made div editable

```
 $('.custom-result-section').each(function(){
    this.contentEditable = true;
});
```

Comment: Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Voted to close this question because : *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: @AniketSahrawat ok ..can you please help

Comment: I am sorry but adding *please* does not make me help you until you help yourself. You should show some efforts and your code that you have a problem with. This is off-topic for SO. You need to post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: now i have added code .. now why ppl are downvoting ????

Comment: select2 is the best plugin for this kind of thing 
https://select2.org/dropdown#templating

Comment: @CalvinNunes plz see the link provided

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use bootstrap and use a code like this

```
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-
              toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-
              expanded="false">Destination <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Miami</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">San Francisco</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Las Vegas</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
```